# How can I map java source code constructs to imports?

Tags: java, parsing, javaparser

The wider context is that I am writing a tool which tries to rough-estimate the consultancy potential of a java developer with respect to various java libraries/technologies across projects in an organization.

The version history of a file gives me the developer who wrote/modified each line of code. If I can map java source code constructs to particular import statements(wherever relevent) I can give come up with a scoring system to assign points to developers for each usage of a java library api.

Comment: While I can at least respect the objective, the usage of libraries or APIs to determine expertise is subjective **at best**.  Why not just read the code to see if it's clear, concise, and accomplishes the objective?  Why not toss in bonus points if there's a unit test written along with it?

Comment: @Makoto, I agree with you that this is subjective. But the larger intent of this tool is to give a birds eye view at an organizational level. Suppose somebody in the organization needs consultancy regarding using a particular piece of technology. He/She can refer to this tool and contact the listed developer(the listed developer may not be able to help at all times). Maybe my use of the word 'expertise' is not appropriate here.

Comment: I don't want to get into a debate about this, but I don't see why the VCS blame tool couldn't be as effective.  Looking at those libraries doesn't add much value in my opinion.  That aside, there is a very simple way to extract exports - look into `JavaCompiler`.

Comment: @Makoto:  "Very Simple"?

Comment: Solution looking for a problem. What makes you think the developers are still going to be around? Average job occupancy in this industry has been under 18 months for decades. And what makes you think the guy who did a completely unevaluated, possibly mediocre, job with this technology last time is the ideal guy for the text one? This really does not make sense.

Answer (score -1):

A novice idea into my mind for this is, if you can just delete last character of each import statement one at a time and by running the class you can get a log of errors which can tell you which code constructs and particularly which classes are not recognizable. By that you can check effect of particular import statement on code.